# VS2017 "File" > "New Website" option missing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I have the ASP.NET and web development tools installed in my Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition but I can't seem to find the "New Website" option, in my VS2015 Edition I use to click "File" > "New" > "Website". If i go to "File" > "Open" the website option is there.

[Picture of my installed tools and extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9qgR.png)

[Picture of missing "New Website"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2bDK.png)

[Picture of "Open Website"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B14pT.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The last way for a software engineer is `Computer Reset`:).

Comment: Does `Shift+Alt+N` works ?

Comment: @Aria I tried restarting, updating my VS to the latest version and `Shift+Alt+N` but nothing works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"New Website" project option is moved "New  Project" dialog.

File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Web -> Web Site

You can create in these way.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful!

Answer (score 9):

In my case with VS 2017 Enterprise, I had to:

File > New Project > Visual C# > Web > Previous Versions

Then I can see the previous dialog options for Site, Razor, etc...

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise C# Website - Previous Versions]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the workaround we came up with:

Create the application first in IIS.  Open IIS Manager, go to the location where you want the website, right click and select Add Application.  Fill out the form and click OK.

Next, open Visual Studio and go to File > Open > Web Site. Select 'Local IIS' on the left, select the application you just created, click Open.  Then just add web.config, etc.